# Disable visual studio xml comments formatting

Tags: xml, visual-studio

```
      <RowDefinition Height="1"/> resharper inserts a new line before the comment
      <!-- row 6 -->
```

what I want is the original

```
      <RowDefinition Height="1"/><!-- row 6 -->
```

preserved as is.
Is there a way to tell visual studio to stop "helping" around comments?
thanks

UPD: oops, seems that visual studio does that idiotic thing without resharper, thusly I'm dropping resharper from the tags and adding visual-studio tag